# How do I revert all changes in a NHibernate session?

Tags: nhibernate

Since the NHibernate ISession tracks changes, I am wondering if I can discard all changes in a session, like this:

```
class Person
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

// Somewhere else...
var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
person.Name = "John Doe";
using(var tx = session.BeginTransaction)
{
    session.Save(person);
    tx.Commit();
}

person.Name = "Jane Doe";
// Now, can I do something like this?
session.RevertAll();
Assert.AreEqual("John Doe", person.Name);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NH does not revert the changes you did in your entities. It is the responsibility of the business logic to care about the state of the entities.

The safest way to "undo" the changes is: rollback the transaction, clear (or recreate) the session and start from scratch.

There is a Reload method in the session. It reloads the state in the database back to the entity. But this does not work for this case, because NH could already have flushed some changes, eg. before performing a query. (It works well for detached entities.)

Comment: @zegar: Short answer: No. Long answer: You could try to mess around with distributed transactions. This is a database server technology (e.g. from SQL Server) and not NHibernate related. I wonder why you want to do this.

Answer (score 2):

```
 session.Refresh(entity); // Cancel object changes, and changes of object collections
```

For cancel editing all objects:

```
 var e = ((SessionImpl)session).PersistenceContext.EntityEntries;
 var allEntities = e.Keys.Cast<object>().ToList();
 foreach (var entity in allEntities)
      session.Refresh(entity);
 //Maybe it's not a good practice...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
session.Clear()
```

With session.Clear, the NHibernate session will not contain any dirty objects anymore.  But, this does not mean that your assertion will work.  NHibernate will not revert the state of your object itself.
In order to achieve this, you'll have to implement undoable-support yourself I guess.  (You could take a look at the `IEditableObject` interface for this).

But, once you've saved and committed / flushed, then the changes have been made into your DB.
session.Clear will not revert those changes offcourse.

Comment: Oh wait, then it simply removes the objects from the session, is that it?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the session flush mode to Commit.

```
session.FlushMode = FlushMode.Commit;
```

When not detached, a data object is either in "transient" or "persisted" state.

Transient objects are new objects which will result in an INSERT statement
when explicitly saved. Persisted objects are objects that will result in an UPDATE statement when the session is Flushed (even if you don't call SaveOrUpdate on that object).

Flushing occurs when the session needs to synchronise the in-memory object container with the database. When flushing occurs, ALL PERSISTED in-memory objects (with in-memory changes) are flushed irrespective if you've called SaveOrUpdate on them. Flush is triggered on a variety of conditions depending on the session's "FlushMode".

The solution that works for me in this case is:

1. Set the Session FlushMode to 'Commit'.
2. Remove all references to 'Flush' in the code handling the in-memory updates on the object.
3. Only ever open 1 transaction per session when 'saving' and then discard that session.